# How to use Azure PowerShell to identify type of service?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I can use Azure Powershell to get a list of services from my subscription e.g. using [Get-AzureService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt589155.aspx).

What I can't currently easily work out is how to tell if the service is a VM (new or classic) or a cloud service (web/worker role).

What I am currently doing to identify a cloud service is using [Get-AzureDeployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt589216.aspx) on the service-name and looking for a non-empty `SdkVersion` property but I feel this is a bit cludgy. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there's no way to do this through the Get-AzureService without using (as you said) the Get-AzureDeployment.

You should be able to fetch the information using the new AzureResourcemanager cmdlets (Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager) and using Get-AzureResource.

The ResourceId (in ARM mode) will give you a clue of what kind of provider it is.